# Highcharts loading data from a HTML table with a title

Tags: html, highcharts, title

I am using the high charts column bar that extracts data from an HTML table but I want to add a title to it. The code I added in the HTML is not working.

The problem is that the graph is not being displayed when I added the title code:

```
    <tr>
      <th COLSPAN='100%'>
         <h3>TITLE</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
```

[Here is the JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5MGwX/)

**HTML:**

```
    400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th COLSPAN='100%'>
                     <h3>TITLE</h3>
                  </th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Jane</th>
                <th>John</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Apples</th>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pears</th>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Plums</th>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bananas</th>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Oranges</th>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('datatable')
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.point.y +' '+ this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Looks like the first part of your HTML is cut off.

Comment: thank you. but you can also just go to the js fiddle link. it has all the code there.

Comment: It may just be the browser I'm using (Chrome), but your Fiddle isn't displaying a graph for me?

Comment: i know. that is the problem. its not working. here, get rid of this code in the html file

<tr>
                  <th COLSPAN='100%'>
                     <h3>TITLE</h3>
                  </th>
                </tr>

and it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your [original JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MGwX/) you had one `<tr>` too many, so your graph was showing, but broken. Removing the `<tr>` lead to [this JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MGwX/3/) giving a:

> Uncaught Highcharts error #14: [www.highcharts.com/errors/14](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14)
>
> String value sent to series.data, expected Number

This is because you are using two rows in your table inside your `<thead>`. The Highcharts data module expects there to only be a single header row. If you look closer you use the console to see that it tries to create a series with the values `["Jane", 3, 2, 5, 1, 2]` when the error above is thrown.

Unfortunately the Highcharts data module isn't that well documented online from what I know, but [looking at the source code](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js) gives us the related options:

> table : String|HTMLElement
>
> A HTML table or the id of such to be parsed as input data. Related options ara startRow,
>   endRow, startColumn and endColumn to delimit what part of the table is used.

Which can be used as follows:

```
data: {
    table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
    startRow: 1
}
```

Using the `startRow: 1` you can manually set the row that marks the start of your table data, as demonstrated in [this JFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5MGwX/4/).

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I would. Outstanding answer.

Comment: Awesome! Any ideas why this chart will not render? I am only trying to use column 1, 3 and 4 https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/11/